# After splitting my code into one file per class - class can't see one "global class"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

My code consists of few classes - some are UI Widgets, some are pure functional and one is to store some global settings (settings from the MainWindow which I am accessing from other Widgets).

I create the "global settings-class" right along with the Mainwindow, everything else is created by the MainWindow or its children. - This works as long as the whole code is in the same file.

To avoid silly scrolling I split up the code into one file per class. The creation of the "global settings-class" remains in the file with the MainWindow.

But now the Children of MainWindow can't access/see the "global settings-class" anymore...

The files are all in the same folder and I tried `import xxx`, `from xxx import *` and `import xxx as x`.

By commenting out all "option"-related code (and losing this functionality) it seems to work.

I just don't see why it shouldn't work after splitting up the whole thing.

Edit - details:

file 1:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        ... # A MenuBar with checkable Items, QAction calls a function which sets the option in o_option instance

    def startWidgetXYZ(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(...)
        self.initAllChecks()
        xyz = XYZ(file, topic, self)
        self.setCentralWidget(xyz)

o_options = MenuBarOptions()   # this is the global
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
m_window = MainWindow()
m_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

file2:

```
class XYZ(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, file, topic, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.k_korpus = Korpus(file, topic)   # the class Korpus will load/save data from/to XML-files
```

file3:

```
class Korpus(object):
    def __init__(self, file, topic):

        self.file = file
        self.level = level
        self.patienceChecked = o_options.isOption123Checked()  # NameError: global name 'o_options' is not defined - (but no error if code is in one file)
```

Comment: Without code and a traceback, this is essentially unanswerable. We can give you vague statements about how you need to make sure the global object is imported everywhere you need it, but without seeing how those imports failed for you we'd just be stabbing in the dark, really.

Comment: ah thanks. I assumed there is something inherent wrong with my whole idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put "global settings-class" in a different file to `MainWindow`. Then in each file (main, file 1 and file 2), add something like

```
from global_settings_file import GlobalSettingsClass
```

Comment: The code itself for the class was already in its own file. After your comment I moved the instantiation from MainWindow away and placed it with the code itself... it works. Thanks!